# How to assign an expression to a model?

Tags: angularjs

I am having the following set up inside an `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<span ng-model="d.attr3">
    {{d.attr2 - d.attr1}}
</span>
```

`d` is the variable used inside `ng-repeat`.

My issue is that I expect `d.attr3` to hold the value of the expression inside `span` tag. However, it holds the expression `NaN`.
Note that I have converted the `d.attr1` and `d.attr2` values to integers - In fact, the expression evaluates correctly but it is not bound to the scope - how do I get `d.attr3` to hold the value of the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span ng-init="d.attr3 = d.attr2 - d.attr1">
    {{d.attr3}}
</span>
```